# Can I get the OpenWhisk Authorization token from the Bluemix web UI?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I've deployed an OpenWhisk action and am successfully invoking it via the `request` package in a node application. To get things to work I have to pass along an `Authorization` header in the HTTP request. The value of that header is the base64-encoded version of `userid:password`.

I can calculate that value at the command line or I can use the -v option of the wsk command to get it, but I can't find it anywhere in the Bluemix web UI. I'm putting together some training materials and would rather not send my users to the command line if I can help it.

Does anybody know how to get this value through the Bluemix UI? If it's there, I haven't seen it.

Comment: How are you setting it to require the `Authorization` header?

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate to the [CLI setup page](https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/learn/cli?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south) on Bluemix. You'll find a box containing the commands to setup your CLI for local usage. That one contains the API key.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but the only API key I see on that page is under Step 2, and it's in the format username:password. That works in wsk, but I can't get it to work at all in my node application. **But** if I take that username:password value and base64 encode it, everything works. That's what I have to use in node, as far as I can tell, and that's what I hope to find in the UI.

Comment: Take the key and split it at the colon, the username is on the left and the password on the right.